# Java REST: @GET and @PUT at the same path?

Tags: java, rest, get, jax-rs, put

I have currently trying to learn the basics of `Java REST`, using `JAX-RS`.

Within the `UserService` class (near bottom) of [this example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/restful/restful_methods.htm) there is both an `@GET` AND `@PUT` method with the same `@path` annotation:

```
@GET
@Path("/users")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public List<User> getUsers() {
   return userDao.getAllUsers();
}
```

and

```
@PUT
@Path("/users")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public String createUser(@FormParam("id") int id,
   @FormParam("name") String name,
   @FormParam("profession") String profession,
   @Context HttpServletResponse servletResponse) throws IOException {
   User user = new User(id, name, profession);
   int result = userDao.addUser(user);
   if(result == 1) {
      return SUCCESS_RESULT;
   }

   return FAILURE_RESULT;
}
```

How does the Program know *which* method to invoke, considering that they are both point at the **same** `@path` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resource classes have `methods` that are `invoked` when specific `HTTP` method `requests` are made, referred to as resource `methods`. In order to create Java methods that will be invoked with specific HTTP methods, a regular Java method must be implemented and annotated with one of the `JAX-RS @HttpMethod` annotated annotations `(namely, @GET, @POST, @PUT, and @DELETE).`

For more info take a look at this [example1](http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=3419) and [example2](https://dzone.com/articles/building-rest-service-collects)

Comment: @java123999 depend on which mode ex: param in url you use get , in form use get or post the get is the default, in ajax use which verbe you want and so on...

Comment: Ok so it depends what you enter after the @path URL? Can you please give an example of formParam, I do not understand it?

Comment: @java123999 look at above links

Answer (score 2):

JAX-RS evaluates the [HTTP method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) of the request and then calls the appropriate Java method in UserService.

Comment: @java123999 it is dependent on the request which the frontend sends to server. Anyway don't confound a HTTP request with a simple URL (or a button click). The request consists of the URL, the HTTP method and headers. JAX-RS routes the request to the most suitable Java method in your resource class based on this information.